# Fody/Costura & CefSharp

Tags: cefsharp, fody-costura

Has anyone tried or had any success embedding CefSharp in their application using Fody/Costura? I am not sure if it's possible, but if it is, I'm not having any luck getting the configuration of Costura correct.

Comment: What have you actually tried? From memory it had problems with the `locales` subfolder.

Comment: @amaitland - I pulled down the entire solution from GitHub and added a test WPF application to the solution so I could test in isolation. I added CefSharp, CefSharp.BrowserSubprocess, CefSharp.Core, and CefSharp.Wpf as project references and set "Copy Local" to true. I added all the files from the distribution folder to a costura32 folder and set Build Action to "Embedded Resource". I updated the FodyWeavers.xml file to include the unmanged resources. I configured CefSettings to look for a specific folder for locales.

Comment: At that point, the program is successfully able to find the dlls and attempt to load, but I get console message: "Failed to launch GPU process".

Comment: The entire message is: [1025/162706.700:ERROR:browser_gpu_channel_host_factory.cc(132)] Failed to launch GPU process.

Comment: Best if you edit your original post with your updated details.

Comment: Using the main project source as a starting point also isn't recommended, better if you use https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample
The `master` branch is a development branch and at any given point slightly unstable.

Comment: Have a read over https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: did you ever have any luck with this?